# Set sgml-mode as default in nXhtml

Tags: html, emacs, nxhtml

Well, I have already provided self-explanatory title. =) I use `nXhtml` for web development, and `sgml-mode` keybindings suite me better. Is there any chance that I can change default mode for HTML editing?

I reckon that this is probably an RTFM issue, but I find `nXhtml` documentation quite uptight. =/

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried standard method of setting mode with

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html?$" . sgml-mode))
```

? I don't use nXhtml, so I don't know how it set handler for HTML files.

Comment: Well, that works for sure, but what I want to do is to change mode withing PHP files. This works only for plain HTML files.

Comment: in this case, you need to re-map keys to match sgml-mode... nXhtml has special handling of html parts in php files, if I correctly understands...